# PGAdmin4 virtual host not working with Apache2 + WSGI

Tags: python, django, apache, apache2, wsgi

I have a problem. I'm creating a server where I will host a Django project and also PGAdmin4. I configured PGAdmin to run through apache2 and WSGI with a Python 3.8 virtual environment. It was working perfectly before I set up the Django project. at the ip/pgadmin. As soon as i manage to host the Django on the virtual host. The pgadmin started not to work.

When trying to enter the "ip/pgadmin" while the django webserver is not at the root at the WSGIScriptAlias i receive this page.

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.0.10 Port 80
```

and the following log error. The pgadmin4 is installed withing the same virtualenv that runs the django project but as they are daemons thats not a problem. So i do not see why is searching under "/var/www/acas_webserver/pgadmin/"

```
[Tue Mar 16 00:54:22.633470 2021] [core:info] [pid 26119:tid 140348751849216] [client 192.168.0.5:63072] AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/acas_webserver/pgadmin/
```

But when i place the django project at the root of the WSGIScriptAlias i reacieve this page but no log info to know what happened.

```
Not Found

The requested resource was not found on this server.
```

I'm trying to get both of them work alone and having my django at the root of the directories of the apache2 virtual hosts + wsgi. I cannot fint whats the problem an its been countless hours without figuring it out. where are the virtual hosts configurations

#django project

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin lemanuel.colon@upr.edu
    ServerName 192.168.0.10
    DocumentRoot /var/www/acas_webserver
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    LogLevel info

    Alias /static /var/www/acas_webserver/static
    <Directory /var/www/acas_webserver/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /media /var/www/acas_webserver/media
    <Directory /var/www/acas_webserver/media>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/acas_webserver/adapts>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess acas_app python-path=/var/www/acas_webserver python-home=/var/www/acas_webserver/my_venv
    WSGIProcessGroup acas_app
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/acas_webserver/adapts/wsgi.py
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

    </VirtualHost>
```

#Pgadming

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 192.168.0.10
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/pgadmin-error.log

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/pgadmin-access.log combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/acas_webserver/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pgadmin4/

    LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
    WSGIDaemonProcess pgadmin processes=1 threads=25 python-home=/var/www/acas_webserver/my_venv
    WSGIScriptAlias /pgadmin /var/www/acas_webserver/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/acas_webserver/my_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pgadmin4/>
            WSGIProcessGroup pgadmin
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
```

I just want to get them work to continue on with this projects and its been several days of headaches. Can someone be of help here? If anything is need im happy to provide. Plz help.

UPDATE:

The problem is all coming up once I enable the django webserver. As soon as i turn of my django webserver on Apache2, i can access my pgadmin page, but as soon as I turn on my django webserver on Apache2, the pgadmin again is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked at your configs ( e.x apache ) and seem fine.

I think, there are many possible ways to solve your problem.
The first way would be using some docker container that fits your needs. if you don't know about it just "GOOGLE: docker Django Postgres apache " and read the top links.
Search for it and there are many results already there. After that, you can run your project probably. I don't want to go deep into docker but surely would solve your problem.

Second, Check and monitor your services, ports, and permissions. If they are not in right place, maybe your server ports are busy or you should restart the services. (as you said worked fine before the Django installation, this idea has a low chance to solve the problem)

Furthermore, You should deploy your Django project in the right folder. the differences between those logs are rational. root folder probably is under a read-only mode.

you have mentioned that you have to work on this project and it's been several days of headaches. My first question is why do you focus on server deployment rather than coding? You can easily run Postgre, WSGI, and Django without any headache  ! ( developing environment)
and pgadmin isn't a necessary tool. Also, if it's the problem and you should use it just ignore it and pass it to the final stage which you have done your coding phases. ( seems you stuck in the first place without coding)

Comment: The thing here is that i have already coded and set up the django webserver and postgresql database. In the past i had PGAdmin4 running on the root and it was working fine. Then i passed it to the /pgadming subdirectory and it was working fine but a soon as i managed to host the django on apache + wsgi it went nuts. I was thinking that i had to do something with the root folder and subdirectory searching on the wrong place. I will look on to the dockers and see any type of solution. I wanted PGAdming to run offline on the local network in case anything happens.

Comment: While playing with the server, i managed to see that the pgadmin was only reachable when the webserver is not available, but as soon as i do "sudo a2dissite django_project" the pgadmin became available again on its subdirectory route.